# Отправка файлов в режиме multiple не хранит порядок

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, upload

Создаю 5 полей upload для загрузки multiple файлов на сервер

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="uploads" id="multipledemo@(counterImportPu)" />
<button type="button" id="@counterImportPu" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" onclick="clearElement(this)">
   Очистить
</button>
```

В контроллер принимаю вот так

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> uploads)
```

Отправляю в первом поле 2 файла, и так же во втором

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но приходит подряд 4 файла,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и сложно понять как их подставить к каждому. Как можно принять их в таком же состоянии как я и отправил, т.е. 0 [1,2], 1[1,2]?

Comment: К файлам идёт сопроводиловка, читайте её. Между парами [0] [2] или [0] [3] в отдельных полях будут метки принадлежности к контролам input. Надеюсь name у ваших input разные. Нажмите стрелочки и посмотрите.

Comment: @nick_n_a если name будут разные, тогда я не смогу их принять в controller, у меня через foreach создается экземпляры загрузки фалов

Comment: эээ... тогда никак. прийдётся городить "веслосипед". Например создать `input type=hidden` и туда javascript-ом записать последовательность. Скорее всего они сложены в порядке как расположены на странице 2 по два. А колличество... javascript.

Comment: @nick_n_a спасибо за помощь)

Comment: Если name разные - вы их замечательно примете. Только вот так  `HttpContext.Current.Request.Files` имя увидите в елементе массива, а вариант велосипеда отпадёт.

Comment: @Unnamed а почему бы вам динамически не наименовать их при создании? а потом на стороне сервера, по названиям уже получать файлы?

Comment: Если на уровне c# не получается разименовать - js в помощь;)

Comment: @nick_n_a HttpContext.Current.Request.Files по моему это не менее извращенный способ, при том что данный способ мне пишет ошибку на Current, у HttpContext нет такого свойства

Comment: @Monomax потому что я не знаю сколько там файлов, и создавать под каждый свой контроллер я думаю не разумно чуть-чуть

Comment: Странно, может совпадение пространств... `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files` это список всех файлов-учасников контекста запроса. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.current?view=netframework-4.7.2 ну... меньше писанины точно.

Comment: @nick_n_a спасибо, да возможно что-то мешало. Ну коллекцию я получаю с уникальными именами, а собственно файлы где? нет разбивки по ним, или я что то опять путаю?

Comment: Я понял, ошибся, там нет разбивки. Удивился (продукту мелкософта) что там нету нужных полей. Хоть весь Http-пакет вручную разбирай. Он конечно есть в Request.InputStream c всеми файлами именами и потрохами, но разбирать его не прикольно.... Пример https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460088/reading-file-input-from-a-multipart-form-data-post/14514351 тут... но мне оно не нравится....

Comment: @nick_n_a z я нашел чуть более другое решение благодаря вам, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Get(0) от туда он уже вытащит файл на 0 индексе и по нейму можно смотреть что к чему относится. Извращенно, но что поделать. Спасибо!